# Docker container: Huge size for Node.js-based microservice

Tags: node.js, docker, microservices, seneca

I've been playing around with setting some microservices in a Docker container where the service is based on Seneca.js. Since this is a Node.js application, I derived the container "FROM node". However, the container image is about 600 MB in size. Not exactly "micro". The eventual application will use a conglomerate of several such service and if each of them is 600+ MB in size, it will blow up the application to several GB.

Am I doing something wrong or is this how you'd go about setting up a Docker-Node.js-based microservice?
Thanks a lot.

Cheers,

Martin

Comment: You could try using the [node:slim](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/) package, and see if that works better for you. Or you can always build your own docker image that only contains the bare minimum of what you need.

Comment: Also share your Dockerfile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on how complicated your service is, you could build it directly off of alpine.  An alpine node box at its most basic looks like this:

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk update && apk add nodejs && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

This image is less than 25 MB.  It also installs `npm` of course, so you can install other dependencies or just mount `package.json` into the working directory, or however else you might want to handle that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Using alpine, the image size is down to 44 MB. With Node:slim is already reduced to 222 MB.

Comment: It's now slightly under 60 MB.